# ionic ion-select directive not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

I am designing select box using ionic Framework. I followed the following link for the usage of ion-select component.

[ion-select component](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/select/Select/)

In the demo emulator shown in above link the select is working fine the select pop up comes on click. but when i tried to use the same code its not working. The component is rendered properly and the pop is not showing.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
        <html ng-app="ionicApp">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

        <title>{{myTitle}}</title>

        <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.2/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.2/js/ionic.bundle.js">
        </script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
            <h1 class="title">ION Select </h1>
        </ion-header-bar>

        <ion-content padding="true">
            <h2>Ion Select</h2>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
                <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender">
                    <ion-option value="f" checked="true">Female</ion-option>
                    <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
                </ion-select>
            </ion-item>

        </ion-content>

    </body>

    </html>
```

CSS

```
body {
 cursor: url('http://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png'), auto;
}
```

JS

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.myTitle = 'ION SELECT'; 

});
```

I have also created a codepen example for the same please find the link below:
[ion-select Codepen](http://codepen.io/anwar069/pen/XKqPbm)

Comment: `ion-select` & `[(ngModel)]` is meant for Angular 2, not for Angular 1

Comment: @ pankaj Thanks for the clearification.. However i am using the latest version of ionic CLI. Do i still need to add angular 2 explicitly?